# Latest Lambda Layer ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-lambda-layers

I have a lambda layer which I keep updating. This lambda layer has multiple versions. How can I find the lambda layer ARN with latest version using aws cli?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am able to do this using the command listed below -

```
aws lambda list-layer-versions --layer-name <layer name> --region us-east-1 --query 'LayerVersions[0].LayerVersionArn'
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if the first position is always the latest, so I ended up sorting in the query: `aws lambda list-layer-versions --layer-name <layer_name> --region us-east-1 --query 'max_by(LayerVersions, &Version).LayerVersionArn'`

Comment: If you look at the full list you will notice the first one is always latest. Also add --output text flag so it returns as straight text instead of text surrouned by quotes

Comment: --query is not supported in the list-layer-versions command

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, it's currently not possible (I have encountered the same issue).

You can keep the latest ARN in your own place (like DynamoDB) and update it whenever you publish a new version of the layer.

Comment: Thanks @Ronyis. I was able to figure out an approach - posted that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom macro to get the latest lambda layer version and use that as a reference.

The following function gets the latest version from the Lambda Layer stack:

```
import json
import boto3


def latest_lambdalayer(event, context):
    
    fragment = get_latestversion(event['fragment'])
    return {
      'requestId': event['requestId'],
      'status': 'success',
      'fragment': fragment
    }

def get_latestversion(fragment):
    cloudformation = boto3.resource('cloudformation')
    stack = cloudformation.Stack('ticketapp-layer-dependencies')
    for o in stack.outputs: 
        if o['OutputKey']=='TicketAppLambdaDependency':
            return o['OutputValue']
    #return "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:899885580749:layer:ticketapp-dependencies-layer:16"
```

And you use this when defining the Lambda layer—here using same global template:

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Layers:
      - !Transform { "Name" : "LatestLambdaLayer"}
    Runtime: nodejs12.x
    MemorySize: 128
    Timeout: 101
```

Comment: I like this answer, but where do you put this code?